# fsolve doesn't work with parametrized function handles

Tags: matlab, solver, numerical

For example, I have defined the following function handles:

```
F = @(x, y, z)[x+y+z; x*y*z];  
funcc = @(x, y)F(x, y, 0);
```

The call

```
res = fsolve(funcc, [10; 10]);
```

Leads to an error:

```
Error using @(x,y)F(x,y,0)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in fsolve (line 219)
        fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Caused by:
Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please re-read the [requirements for the objective function in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#inputarg_fun). The function must take a a single vector input and return a vector. You're trying to pass two scalars. Instead:

```
F = @(x, y, z)[x+y+z; x*y*z];
funcc = @(x)F(x(1), x(2), 0);
```

The input to the objective function should match your initial guess, `x0` (`[10; 10]`).